# Domain of $\ln(1+\frac{1}{x})$

Tags: real-analysis, functions, logarithms

What is the definition domain of $\ln(1+\frac{1}{x})$ and why it's not the same as for $\ln(x+1)-\ln(x)$ ? Both functions are not defined on $0$. For the second form, the DF is $(0,+\infty)$ while for the first one is $(-\infty,-1) \cup (0,+\infty)$

Comment: The real $\log$ function is only defined for positive argument, and the rule $\log xy = \log x + \log y$ requires both $x$ and $y$ to be positive.  Thus, just like your example,  $\log (x^2) \neq 2 \log x$ when $x < 0$ although the left hand side is perfectly well defined.

Comment: But when. I plot these functions I get the same graph ! Is this an error from my symbolic math software ? (log(1+1/x) and log(1+x)-log(x)). However it works for your example

Comment: What do you use for plotting the curve?

Comment: Wolfram Alpha (mathematica)

Comment: It's possible that the symbolic math software assigns a complex value to the $\log$ of a negative number, so for $x<-1$, $\log(x+1) = \log |x+1| + \pi i = \log(-x-1) + \pi i$ and $\log x = \log|x| + \pi i = \log (-x) + \pi i$.  The imaginary parts cancel when subtracted and you get the desired answer.  But this is a happy coincidence, as the complex $\log$ functions does not always satisfy $\log (z_1z_2) = \log(z_1) + \log(z_2)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expressions "$\log(1+\frac 1x)$" and "$\log(x+1)-\log x$" are only equivalent when they are both defined, i.e. when $x > 0$. If you are getting the same graph, this means that the software is making some unsolicited simplifications to the second expression.

For instance, Wolfram Mathematica evaluates $\log (x+1)$ and $\log x$ to complex values when the arguments are negative, and the imaginary parts vanish when it takes the difference, except for $x \in (-1,0)$.

Comment: could you please tell me if my reasoning is correct about the formal derivation of the domain ?  If $x> 0$ we have  $1 + 1 / x> 0$, but if x <0 then  :  $1+1/x > 0   \to  1/x > -1  \to 1 <x  \to x <-1$

Comment: The final result is correct but, in terms of reasoning, you can just solve the inequality $1+\frac 1x > 0 \Leftrightarrow \frac{x+1}{x} > 0$. The fraction is positive if both polynomials are positive (yielding $x>0$) or if both polynomials are negative (yielding $x < -1$).

Answer (score 1):

Their domains are not the same because $\ln(x)$ is not defined for $x\leqslant 0$. Therefore $\ln(x+1)-\ln(x)$ is not defined for $x\leqslant 0$. However, $\ln(1+\frac{1}{x})$ is defined when $x<-1$. Take an $x<-1$ then $1+\frac{1}{x}>0$ and therefore $\ln(1+\frac{1}{x})$ is defined for $x<-1$.

Comment: But when. I plot these functions I get the same graph ! Is this an error from my symbolic math software ?

Comment: @ZchGarinch Try plotting it in Desmos too, it will give you the right plot. Note that checking the plot is not a reliable way of checking whether two functions have the same domain. For instance for some calculators $\frac{x^2+x}{x}$ might display the same plot as $x+1$ but their domains are different (since one is defined in 0 and the other is not).

Comment: @ZchGarinch Some math software is just too smart... It evaluates the logarithms even with negative argument (yielding complex numbers) but the imaginary parts vanishes when taking the difference and the software is able to plot the difference, even if it can not plot both terms independently.

Answer (score 1):

The relation $f$ defined by $f(x)=\ln(x+1)$ on $\mathbb{R}$ can only be given a domain that is a subset of $\{x:x\gt-1\}$ for it to be a function. The relation $g$ defined by $g(x)=\ln(x)$ on $\mathbb{R}$ can only be given a domain that is a subset of $\{x:x\gt0\}$ for it to be a function. Thus the relation $h=f-g$ is a function if and only if it is given a domain that is a subset of $\{x:x\gt-1\}\cap{\{x:x\gt0\}}=\{x:x\gt0\}$. Meanwhile, the relation $j$ defined by $j(x)=\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)$ on $\mathbb{R}$ can given a domain that is a subset of $\{x:1+1/x\gt0\}=\{x:1/x\gt-1\}=\{x:x\lt-1\lor{x\gt0}\}$. Notice that $\{x:x\lt-1\lor{x\gt0}\}\setminus\{x:x\gt0\}=\{x:x\lt-1\}$. As such, $\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)=\ln(x+1)-\ln(x)$ for every $x\gt0$, but the left-hand side exists for $x\lt-1$, while the right-hand side does not.

What is happening is that $1+\frac{1}{x}\gt0$ when $x\lt-1$, yet $x\lt0$ and $x+1\lt0$, which occurs because even if $s\lt0$ and $t\lt0$, $\frac{s}t\gt0$. Many mathematical softwares are not programmed to account for this, and so, despite it being incorrect, they give both $j$ and $h$ the same plots for their graphs.

Many people make a similar mistake when handling the expression $\ln(x^2)$. They always write $2\ln(x)$, which is incorrect. The correct expression is $2\ln(|x|)$. The equation $\ln(|xy|)=\ln(|x|)+\ln(|y|)$ is correct for every $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$, but $\ln(xy)=\ln(x)+\ln(y)$ is only correct for $x\gt0,y\gt0$. Computers can make this mistake too, since computers are programmed by fallible, mistake-making humans.

Answer (score 0):

$log$ of negative values has same complex output: $\ln(-ve) = (\ln (ve) + i\pi)$
Thus, $$\ln(1+x)-\ln(x) =\ln(-ve_1) + \ln(-ve_2) = (\ln (ve_1) + i\pi)-(\ln(ve_2)+i\pi) = \ln\left(\frac {-ve_1}{-ve_2}\right) = \ln(\frac {ve_1}{ve_2})$$
*But*, for software(except few too smart softwares):
$$D:f+ g = D:f \cap D:g \implies (\mathbb R - [-1, 0]) \cap (\mathbb R^+ - 0)$$